# Mathematica code for Newton's Method doesn't work

Tags: equation-solving, recursion

I am trying to program Newton's Method in Mathematica to compute the roots of $f(x)=x^3-6x^2+11x-6$ using the `Do` command but my code gives a `General::ivar` error and doesn't work and I can't figure out what is wrong with it:

```
f[x_] := x^3 - 6*x^2 + 11*x - 6
g[x_] := D[f[x], x]
a[0] = 0;
Do[a[n + 1] = a[n] - N[f[a[n]]/g[a[n]]], {n, 0, 100}]

Table[a[n], {n, 0, 100}]
```

Can you explain what's wrong with it?

Comment: `g[x_] = D[f[x], x]` works, but the reasoning is a bit complicated for a comment. See `Set` vs `SetDelayed` in the documentation. This also might help with that: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/18393/what-are-the-most-common-pitfalls-awaiting-new-users/18487#18487

Answer (score 4):

This would be more idiomatic:

```
Clear[f, g, newtonIteration]

f[x_] := x^3 - 6*x^2 + 11*x - 6
g[x_] = D[f[x], x];

newtonIteration[previousEstimate_] :=
 previousEstimate - f[previousEstimate]/g[previousEstimate]

FixedPointList[
  newtonIteration,
  0.  (* starting value *),
  100 (* max number of iterations *)
]

(* Out: {0., 0.545455, 0.848953, 0.974674, 0.999092, 0.999999, 1., 1., 1.} *)
```

Even shorter, with pure functions:

```
FixedPointList[# - f[#]/g[#] &, 0., 100]
```

The third argument of [`FixedPointList`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FixedPointList.html) (the `100`) is there to as a fail-safe, to stop runaway iterations that do not converge after 100 steps.

You want to use `Set` (`=`) instead of `SetDelayed` (`:=`) here to define the derivative `g`, so it is calculated symbolically and stored in `g`, and then numerical values of `x` are substituted as needed. On the other hand, using `SetDelayed` (`:=`) forces the re-calculation of the derivative at each step. In particular, this means that `x` will have already been assigned a numerical value at that point. and it will no longer be a valid variable for differentiation. This was the origin of the error in your original code.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question:

Notice the change in definition of `f[x], g[x]`

```
Clear[f, g, a]
f[x_] = x^3 - 6*x^2 + 11*x - 6
g[x_] = D[f[x], x]
a[0] = 0;
Do[a[n + 1] = a[n] - N[f[a[n]]/g[a[n]]], {n, 0, 7}]
Table[a[n], {n, 0, 7}]
```

> {0, 0.545455, 0.848953, 0.974674, 0.999092, 0.999999, 1., 1.}

---

Save your work before you run such loops.

To help you understand it further:

```
Clear[f, g, a]
f[x_] = x^3 - 6*x^2 + 11*x - 6
g[x_] = D[f[x], x]
a[0] = 0;
Do[a[n + 1] = a[n] - N[f[a[n]]/g[a[n]]];
 Echo[a[n] , "a[" <> ToString@n <> "] = "];
 Pause[1];
 , {n, 0, 10}]
```

Now you can try with the `SetDelayed :=`  and see the difference.

Keep the `Pause` in there or it would be hard to abort evaluation in cases where it misbehaves.